# How to connect leaflet map clicks (events) with plot creation in a shiny app

Tags: events, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

Hello I am creating an environmental shiny app in which I want to use a leaflet map to create some simple plots based on openair package(https://rpubs.com/NateByers/Openair).

Aq_measurements() general form

`AQ<- (aq_measurements(country = “country”, city = “city”, location = “location”, parameter = “pollutant choice”, date_from = “YYYdateY-MM-DD”, date_to = “YYYY-MM-DD”)`.

All parameters available in locations dataframe.

worldmet() general form

```
met <- importNOAA(code = "12345-12345", year = YYYYY:YYYY)
```

NOAA Code available in locations dataframe

Below I create a sample of my initial data frame:

```
location = c("100 ail","16th and Whitmore","40AB01 - ANTWERPEN") 
lastUpdated = c("2018-02-01 09:30:00", "2018-02-01 03:00:00", "2017-03-07 10:00:00") 
firstUpdated = c("2015-09-01 00:00:00","2016-03-06 19:00:00","2016-11-22 15:00:00")
pm25=c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE")
pm10=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE")
no2=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE")
latitude=c(47.932907,41.322470,36.809700)
longitude=c(106.92139000,-95.93799000
,-107.65170000)

df = data.frame(location, lastUpdated, firstUpdated,latitude,longitude,pm25,pm10,no2)
```

As a general idea I want to be able to click on a certain location in the map based on this dataframe. Then I have one `selectInput()` and 2 `dateInput()`. The 2 `dateInput()` should take as inputs the `df$firstUpdated` and `df$lastUpdated` respectively. Then the `selectInput()` should take as inputs the pollutants that exist in the `df` based on "TRUE"/"FALSE" value. And then the plots should be created. All of these should be triggered by clicking on the map.

Up to now I was not able to achieve this so in order to help you understand I connected the `selectInput()` and the `dateInput()` with `input$loc` which is a `selectIpnut()` with locations in the first tab as I will not need this when I find the solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)
library(htmltools)
library(DT)
library(utilr)
library(openair)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gissr)
library(ropenaq)
library(worldmet)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
   ui = navbarPage("ROPENAQ",
           tabPanel("CREATE DATAFRAME",
                    sidebarLayout(

                      # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                      sidebarPanel(
                        wellPanel(
                          uiOutput("loc"),
                          helpText("Choose a Location to create the dataframe.")
                        )
                        ),
                      mainPanel(

                      )
                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("LEAFLET MAP",
                    leafletOutput("map"),
                    wellPanel(
                      uiOutput("dt"),
                      uiOutput("dt2"),
                      helpText("Choose a start and end date for the dataframe creation. Select up to 2 dates")
                    ),
                    "Select your Pollutant",
                    uiOutput("pollutant"),                     

                    helpText("While all pollutants are listed here, not all pollutants are measured at all locations and all times.  
                             Results may not be available; this will be corrected in further revisions of the app.  Please refer to the measurement availability 
                             in the 'popup' on the map."),

                    hr(),
                    fluidRow(column(8, plotOutput("tim")),
                             column(4,plotOutput("polv"))),
                    hr(),

                    fluidRow(column(4, plotOutput("win")),
                             column(8,plotOutput("cal"))),
                    hr(),
                    fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("ser"))
                             )
           )


)

#server.r

# load data
# veh_data_full <- readRDS("veh_data_full.RDS")
# veh_data_time_var_type <- readRDS("veh_data_time_var_type.RDS")
df$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , df$location)
server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$pollutant<-renderUI({
      selectInput("pollutant", label = h4("Choose Pollutant"), 
                  choices = colnames(df[,6:8]), 
                  selected = 1)
    })


    #Stores the value of the pollutant selection to pass to openAQ request      

    ###################################
   #output$OALpollutant <- renderUI({OALpollutant})


    ##################################
    # create the map, using dataframe 'locations' which is polled daily (using ropenaq)
    #MOD TO CONSIDER: addd all available measurements to the popup - true/false for each pollutant, and dates of operation.


    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE")))%>% addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(lng = subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$longitude, lat = subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$latitude,
                   popup = paste("Location:", subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$location, "<br>",
                                 "Pollutant:", input$pollutant, "<br>",
                                 "First Update:", subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$firstUpdated, "<br>",
                                 "Last Update:", subset(df,(df[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$lastUpdated
                                 ))
    })
    #Process Tab
   OAL_site <- reactive({
        req(input$map_marker_click)
        location %>%
            filter(latitude == input$map_marker_click$lat,
                   longitude == input$map_marker_click$lng)

###########
        #call Functions for data retrieval and processing.  Might be best to put all data request
        #functions into a seperate single function.  Need to:
        # call importNOAA() to retrieve meteorology data into temporary data frame
        # call aq_measurements() to retrieve air quality into a temporary data frame
        # merge meteorology and air quality datasets into one working dataset for computations; temporary
        # meteorology and air quality datasets to be removed.
        # call openAir() functions to create plots from merged file.  Pass output to a dashboard to assemble 
        # into appealing output.
        # produce output, either as direct download, or as an emailable PDF.
        # delete all temporary files and reset for next run.
    })
   #fun 

   output$loc<-renderUI({
     selectInput("loc", label = h4("Choose location"),
                 choices = df$location ,selected = 1
     )
   })

   output$dt<-renderUI({

                 dateInput('date',
                           label = 'First Available Date',
                           value = subset(df$firstUpdated,(df[,1]==input$loc))
                 )           


   })
   output$dt2<-renderUI({

                 dateInput('date2',
                           label = 'Last available Date',
                           value = subset(df$lastUpdated,(df[,1]==input$loc))
                 )            


   })

   rt<-reactive({


     AQ<- aq_measurements(location = input$loc, date_from = input$dt,date_to = input$dt2,parameter = input$pollutant)
     met <- importNOAA(year = 2014:2018)
     colnames(AQ)[9] <- "date"
     merged<-merge(AQ, met, by="date")
     # date output -- reports user-selected state & stop dates in UI
     merged$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , merged$location)

     merged


   })
   #DT  

     output$tim = renderPlot({
       timeVariation(rt(), pollutant = "value")
     })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The part of my code that I believe input$MAPID_click should be applied is:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE")))%>% addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(lng = subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$longitude, lat = subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$latitude,
                   popup = paste("Location:", subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$location, "<br>",
                                 "Pollutant:", input$pollutant, "<br>",
                                 "First Update:", subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$firstUpdated, "<br>",
                                 "Last Update:", subset(locations,(locations[,input$pollutant]=="TRUE"))$lastUpdated
                   ))
    })  

  output$dt<-renderUI({

                 dateInput('date',
                           label = 'First Available Date',
                           value = subset(locations$firstUpdated,(locations[,1]==input$loc))
                 )           


   })
   output$dt2<-renderUI({

                 dateInput('date2',
                           label = 'Last available Date',
                           value = subset(locations$lastUpdated,(locations[,1]==input$loc))
                 )            


   })


   rt<-reactive({



     AQ<- aq_measurements(location = input$loc, date_from = input$dt,date_to = input$dt2)
     met <- importNOAA(year = 2014:2018)
     colnames(AQ)[9] <- "date"
     merged<-merge(AQ, met, by="date")
     # date output -- reports user-selected state & stop dates in UI
     merged$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , merged$location)

     merged


   })
   #DT  










     output$tim = renderPlot({
       timeVariation(rt(), pollutant = "value")
     })
```

Comment: it is unclear what you want. For instance what kind of plot you want? You should also provide a **minimal** example. It might be easier to get help. Your code is long and a bit messy and hard to follow.

Comment: I editted in order to display how you can plot with openair. This is not the problem as the plots are really simple. What I basically want to do is replace what the functionallity of input$loc with leaflet interactivity. I want the rt() function to take as inputs values from the map when I click on them and not from the selectInput that I use as an example. If you run the code you will some locations in the first tab that activate everything. I want this functionality but by the map.

Comment: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-tricks-for-working-with-r-leaflet-and-shiny/ Trick 2 here might give an idea of funtionality I wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a minimal example. You click on your marker and you get a plot.

```
ui = fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  textOutput("temp"),
  plotOutput('tim')
)

#server.r

#df$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , df$location)
server = function(input, output, session) {


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df)%>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(lng = longitude, lat = latitude)
  })

  output$temp <- renderPrint({

    input$map_marker_click$lng
  })

  output$tim <- renderPlot({
    temp <- df %>% filter(longitude == input$map_marker_click$lng)
   # timeVariation(temp, pollutant = "value")
    print(ggplot(data = temp, aes(longitude, latitude)) + geom_point())
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Certainly to the right direction I could say but I would like to ask: Why do you use only lng? Also  the AQ<- aq_measurements(location = locations$location, date_from=locations$firstUpdated,date_to = locations$lastUpdated) should take as inputs certain types of values,meaning the location,firstUpdated,lastUpdated from the relative lat and long. Then it creates the merged file whhich is beeing passed to the plot.

Comment: sth like this? rt<-reactive({   
   temp <- locations %>% filter(longitude == input$map_marker_click$lng)%>%
   aq_measurements(location = ~location, date_from = ~firstUpdated,date_to = ~lastUpdated)
   met <- importNOAA(year = 2014:2018)
   colnames(temp)[9] <- "date"
   merged<-merge(AQ, met, by="date")
   # date output -- reports user-selected state & stop dates in UI
   merged$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , merged$location)
   
   merged
   
   
})

Comment: As I said It was not clear to me what you wanted. So I started from the bottom. You click on one point and you get your plot. Starting from there It will easier to add the filters you want to implement. I am not sure why locations is still in reactive function because clicking on the map gives you the location. I used only longitude assuming it was unique but you can also add latitude if you want.

Comment: I used this: output$tim = renderPlot({
       temp <- locations %>% filter(longitude == input$map_marker_click$lng)%>%
         aq_measurements(country= ~country,location = ~location, date_from = ~firstUpdated,date_to = ~lastUpdated,parameter = input$pollutant)
       met <- importNOAA(year = 2014:2018)
       colnames(temp)[9] <- "date"
       merged<-merge(temp, met, by="date")
       # date output -- reports user-selected state & stop dates in UI
       merged$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , merged$location)
       
       
       timeVariation(merged, pollutant = "value")
     })

Comment: Error:'match' requires vector arguments

Comment: it might be easier if you edit your original post. It is hard to tell in the comment section. I am glad you are getting close!

Comment: thanks @firmo23 for accepting the answer and I am glad I could be helpful.